# DataGridView extremly slow initial load time

Tags: c#, winforms, optimization, datagridview

I have DataGridView with 4 rows and 2 columns, very little data.

> *Initially it takes about 3 and sometimes up to 5-7 seconds for DataGridView to load...*

After I close the Form with DataGridView and reopen it it takes a moment to paint.

What's the deal with such long initial load - any suggestions?

I use EntityFramework to fetch the data if this information helps anyone

*How can I hack DataGridView to make it load faster?*

p.s. a lot of posts with the same issue, but all of them have large amount of rows and data, this is not the case over here

UPDATE: Turns out this is either Entity Framework or Database engine issue, if I manage to get better performance I will post results

Comment: Could it simply be the DBMS connection that eats up the time, e.g. by waking up the remote server etc..?

Comment: I'm using LocalDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long does it take to retrieve the data in isolation, i.e. without displaying it via the DGV?

I strongly suspect this is a problem with either the database engine or the way you're retrieving the data via EF. I cut out these aspects of the application in the following example and it displays instantly on my machine:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    class MyData
    {
        public string Somestring { get; set; }
        public string Anotherstring { get; set; }
        public MyData(string some, string another) {
            Somestring = some;
            Anotherstring = another;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var data = new List<MyData> {
            new MyData("First Row, First Column", "First Row, Second Column"), 
            new MyData("Second Row, First Column", "Second Row, Second Column"),
            new MyData("Third Row, First Column", "Third Row, Second Column"),
            new MyData("Fourth Row, First Column", "Fourth Row, Second Column")
        };

        var source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = data;
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
    }
}
```

(You should already have created a new WinForms project and added a new DataGridView to the default form.)

There will be some startup time necessary for LocalDB, which may explain the delay. If your data doesn't change often, you could cache the results between runs and refresh in the background; alternatively I'd recommend using a more lightweight database engine such as SQLite.

Comment: OK it seems that it's database engine problem, but still why would it take so much time for 4 rows? ... hmm how can I solve this - thanks for reply btw

Comment: Does the caching of the query results make the performace slow?

Comment: Since you made me realize this is not a DGV issue your answer is technically acceptable

Comment: @ChenChi - I don't think it's the retrieval that's taking a long time, rather the time to startup LocalDB itself. It's a fully featured SQL Server instance, so it's much more complex than something like SQLite. To be frank, if you're just storing and retrieving a few rows of data, it's like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut ;)

Comment: Yes but I'm just starting to develop this app, in future it's gonna be much more rows and maybe even multiple-users over network... probably gonna end up using SQL SE and not LocalDB - from what I've researched issue might be in Entity Framework inital load time too?